# how to compute the dynamic price of items in cart and output the total

Tags: php, html

When a user add items to its cart it will be hold on my temporary database table user_cart and there will be an output of the item in the cart page which the user will see their items in their cart. so the php code i used is while loop to output the items. how to compute all the item price and output it on the total section?

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th class="text-center">Price</th>
            <th class="text-center">Total</th>
            <th> </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php
            $count = 1;
            $cart_query = "Select * from user_cart where email = '$email'";
            $cart_res = mysqli_query($con,$cart_query);
            while($cart_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cart_res)) {
        ?>
            <td class="col-sm-8 col-md-6">
            <div class="media">
                <a class="thumbnail pull-left" href="#"> <?php
                $image_count = 1;
                $product_name = stripslashes($cart_row["product_name"]);
                $image_query = "Select * from tbl_products where item_category = 'Laptop' AND item_name = '$product_name'";
                $image_res = mysqli_query($con,$image_query);
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($image_res)){
                $imageData = $row["images"];
                echo '<img src ="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($imageData).'"class="img-responsive" style = "width:100px; height:80px;"/>';?>
                <?php $count++; } ?>
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                 <h4 class="media-heading"><a href="#"><?php echo stripslashes($cart_row["product_name"]);?></a></h4>
                <h5 class="media-heading"> by <a href="#"><?php echo $cart_row["brand"];?></a></h5>
                <span>Status: </span>
                <span class="text-success">
                <strong><?php echo $cart_row["item_available"];?></strong>
                </span>
                </div>
            </div></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1" style="text-align: center">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" value="<?php echo $cart_row["quantity"];?>">
            </td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center">
            <strong><?php echo $cart_row["item_price"];?></strong></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 text-center" id = "item_total_price">
            <strong><?php echo $cart_row["item_total_price"];?></strong></td>
            <td class="col-sm-1 col-md-1">
            <form action  = "functions/delete.php" method = "post">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
             <input type = "hidden" value = "<?php echo $cart_row['cart_id'];?>" name = "cart_id">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
            </button></td>
            </form>
            </tr>
            <?php $count++; } ?>
            <tr>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
            <td class="text-right" id = "sub_total">
            <h5><strong></strong></h5></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <h3><strong>$31.53</strong></h3>
            </td></tr>
            <tr>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>   </td>
            <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart">
            </span> Continue Shopping</button></td>
            <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                Checkout <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>
            </button></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the trouble to add to cart when calculating the total price and record in a table,another is a SQL calculation : "select sum('goos_price') * buys_count as total_price from your_table";if use php :$total_price  = 0;foreach($cart_data as $key=>$val){ $total_price = $val['goos_price'] * $val['buys_count'];}

Comment: very helpful then :)

Comment: how can i echo this statement? $subtotal_statement = "SELECT SUM(item_price) FROM user_cart WHERE email = '$email'"; i tried using xampp shell and i get the results but i dont know how to output it?